# How to send Intune scopes to Microsoft authentication?

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I would like to get the list of devices available in my Intune Account using a periodic webjob.

I created the app in Azure, got my clientId and clientSecret, I added the permission **DeviceManagementManagedDevices.ReadWrite.All**:

[image]

In Azure, the scope is:

[image]

Here is the code to get the Token:

```
    private async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetAuthorizationHeaderAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Building ConfidentialClientApplication.");
        var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_intuneSettings.ClientId)
            .WithClientSecret(_intuneSettings.ClientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri(_intuneSettings.Authority))
            .Build();

        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/DeviceManagementManagedDevices.ReadWrite.All" };

        _logger.LogInformation("Acquiring Token.");
        var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
            .ExecuteAsync();

        _logger.LogInformation($"Token: {result.AccessToken}");
        return result;
    }
```

But I got an error;

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception
>   while executing function:
>   AirWatchMobileErasorService.ExecuteAirWatchMobileErasorAsync --->
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: AADSTS70011: The
>   provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided
>   value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/DeviceManagementManagedDevices.ReadWrite.All
>   is not valid.

I tried to use:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
```

I can get the Token, but when I try to get the list of devices:

```
        var authHeader = await GetAuthorizationHeaderAsync();
        var graphClient = new HttpClient();
        graphClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader.CreateAuthorizationHeader());
        var result = await graphClient.GetStringAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices");
```

I got a 401 unauthorized exception:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception
>   while executing function:
>   AirWatchMobileErasorService.ExecuteAirWatchMobileErasorAsync --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not
>   indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

How can I get the list of devices available in Intune?

Answer (score 0):

As I want to use a webjob, I need to select Application and not Delegated in Azure:

[image]

And I use this code to connect:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
```

Comment: The answer will accepted in 2 days (just in case someone ask, there is a delay before accepting)